# Can I transfer all my WhatsApp info from Android to Windows Phone?

Tags: whatsapp

Can I transfer all my WhatsApp info (contacts, chats, photos, videos etc) from my Android phone to my Lumia 1520?

Comment: Have you tried signing in with the same account? I would expect that to bring across at least your contacts...

Comment: OK. Thanx a lot for the info.

Answer (score 1):

The last time I did this, it worked fine for me once I logged in with the same phone number. All of my contacts were available again on the new phone. Chats, photo's and videos were not available on my new phone.

Comment: OK. Thanx a lot for the info.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't transfer all your information from Android to Windows Phone. But you can transfer most part of it. Contacts are linked to your what'sapp account, so you can transfer it in some way. Photos and videos can be transferred through Bluetooth, or even manually coping and pasting using a PC. But chats, there is no way to   transfer it, because you need to verify your what'sapp account every time you change the device you are using. I use a           Windows Phone and a Android device, and use then alternately in a two weeks routine. What I've notice regarding the chat is that the chat history continues from were you left on the same device, so the conversation kept in my Windows Phone will be from two weeks later and vice versa for my Android device.